# only showing the profile_image for the first user in the db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have an app where users can make profiles, attend events and comment on events. The issue I'm running into is for example: when user A posts a comment, and user B posts a comment both users have user A's profile_image beside their respective comment.

Here's the code to help me this clearer:

**events_controller.rb snippit**

```
def create
    @event = current_user.events.new(event_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @event }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @commentable = @event
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @event.comments.new
  end
```

**_comment.html.erb (partial rendered  in events/show.html)**

```
<div class="comment">                                                                                                                                         
  <%= simple_user_avatar(@user) %> <%= comment.user.name %> (<small><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) + " ago" %></small>):<br /><br />               
  <div><%= simple_format comment.body %></div>                                                                                                                
</div>
```

**simple_user_avatar helper method in helpers.rb**

```
 def simple_user_avatar(user)
    if user.profile_image.present?
      html = link_to (image_tag user.profile_image_url(:small).to_s), user
    else
      html = link_to (image_tag "profile-placeholder1.png", size: '50x50'), user
    end
    return html
  end
```

What am I doing wrong? and how can I have it so beside each user's comment shows their own personal profile_image, and not every user that posts a comment has User A's profile_image beside their comment.

Comment: you only get avatar of `@user`, which is user of event. I think you have to use `simple_user_avatar(comment.user)` to get profile image of users commented.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Kien Thanh pointed out, you are using the wrong user for displaying the profile image.  Also, it seems like you have incorrect show action in your EventsController. You are using the same params[:id] to search for User and Event. If you have a nested route where :users resources is nested under :events resources, then your show action will be:

```
def show
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  @commentable = @event
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @comment = @event.comments.new
end
```

The code for your simple_user_avatar in the comments partial should be:

```
<%= simple_user_avatar(comment.user) %>
```

You want to get the user that made the comment and pass that to the simple_user_avatar helper so that the profile pic changes according to the user who commented.